# Outputting R data in shiny bar chart

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to ouput my data into a graph. I assumed from the example (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html) the code below is ok, but it just throws back errors.

The below code outputs my data into the table:

[image]

If I wanted to get "date_start" on the X axis and "clicks" on the Y axis what is the simplest way todo that?

```
  # Getting the output into a tidy dataframe
  content_result <- content(report)
  content_result[["paging"]] <- NULL
  result_data <- content_result$data
  result_data <- result_data %>% reduce(bind_rows)


  # Setting classes of variables - numerical, data, etc and putting into a frame called 'import'
  result_data$impressions <- as.numeric(result_data$impressions)
  result_data$unique_clicks <- as.numeric(result_data$unique_clicks)
  result_data$clicks <- as.numeric(result_data$clicks)
  result_data$spend <- as.numeric(result_data$spend)
  result_data$date_start <- as.Date(result_data$date_start)
  result_data$date_stop <- as.Date(result_data$date_stop)

  import <- result_data


sum_by_day <- import  %>%
    group_by(date_start) %>%
    summarise(clicks = sum(clicks), impressions = sum(impressions), spend=sum(spend)) %>%
    mutate(CPC_new=spend/clicks) %>%
    mutate(CTR_new=clicks / impressions)
```

The server.R is:

```
   output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({

    # Render a barplot
    barplot(sum_by_day[,clicks, 
            main=clicks,
            ylab="Number of clicks",
            xlab="Year")
  })
```

Any help apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some errors:

1. I assumed you want to order the data after the date
2. You forgot to use the ui.R file from the example
3. Your first vector in the barplot function is completely wrong. It should be the y-variable
4. In `main` you need a single string not an R variable
5. Your shiny architecture is missing (cf. https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/)

The corrected code (this file has to be called app.r):

```
    library(shiny)

sum_by_day<-data.frame(date_start=17637:17643,
                   clicks=c(32,30,38,26,27,35,27),
                   impressions=c(4226,3918,2763,2913,2989,2908,2973),
                   spend =c(31.5,32.08,31.32,30.47,30.28,29.32,31.19),
                   CPC_new=c(0.98,1.07,0.82,1.17,1.12,0.84,1.16),
                   CTR_new=rep(0.01,7))


## ui.r

ui<-fluidPage(    

  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Barplot by KPI"),

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("my_kpi", "Choose KPI:", 
                  choices=colnames(sum_by_day)[-1]),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")
    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )

  )
)


## server.r
server<-function(input, output){
  output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({

    tmp<-sum_by_day[order(sum_by_day[,input$my_kpi]),input$my_kpi]
    names(tmp)
    names(tmp)<-sum_by_day$date_start[order(sum_by_day[,input$my_kpi])]

    # Render a barplot
    barplot(tmp,main=as.character(input$my_kpi),
                     ylab=as.character(input$my_kpi),
                     xlab="Time")
  })
}

## deploy!
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  When I put this in a file and run app i get the error: Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'mydata' not found.  Im assuming this is because of the line: choices=colnames(mydata)[-1])

What is the mydata and the [-1] referencing?

Comment: my bad. At first instead of `sum_by_day` I called it `mydata`. Replace this with `colnames(sum_by_day)[-1]` and it should work. 

The `[-1] ` removes the first column name - in your case `date_start` from the list. I mean it doesn't make sense to plot date_start against date_start, right?

Happy I understood everything, if it works for you can give it vote up and accept it as answer ;)

Comment: That worked great, thank you very much...I have been staring at that for 2 days now and got no where.

Comment: Happens to everyone. Just make sure you organise your next question a bit better. Many people only look at your question for a short moment and if they don't get it they move on. There is some advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Generally try to ask the question early - at best before the code. It really helps getting more replies